# Twitter bootstrap carousel youtube video auto start

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I have created a Twitter Bootstrap carousel to display pictures and text. So far this goes great.
But I would like to add YouTube videos to the slides, I would like the videos to automatically start playing and when the video is finished I would like for the carousel to go to the next slide.

I have tried to accomplish something like this using the YouTube `?autoplay=1` option, but because all the divs are loaded on start up the video starts to play when the page is loaded. I have yet to find anything near a solution for the waiting until video ends problem.

I hope somebody could help me along.

EDIT: 
http://pastie.org/6348104
That's the code I use for the carousel.
The carousel is fully functional but I have the Bootstrap files stored locally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll probably want to attach YouTube's `player.playVideo()` [(example)](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Examples) function as a callback on the `carousel('cycle')` function.

Comment: But how would I now what slide is next? Because if the next slide for instance slide 2 is a photo, then I do not want to call `player.playVideo()`. But if the next slide is slide 3 and is slide 3 a video then I do want to call `player.playVideo()`.

Comment: Since you haven't provided any code, it's hard to say what would work in your scenario.

Comment: I have added a link to my code, I hope you know a way to solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
style="transform: none;"
```

to your `div` in `modal pop up` with `class="modal-dialog"`

to your modal dialogue